# How do you create a javascript api to allow the viewer to draw?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've tried searching and searching for this in javascript libaries and on the web but I haven't found anything. If you don't get what I mean I mean something like [this](http://slimber.com/painter/)

Comment: apply some of your searched methods and post the actual programming issue here when you encounter one.

Comment: Here's a website you can read about lots of js frameworks at one spot. http://jster.net/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a more specific question for us to attempt to answer or explain what you've tried / explored and where your pain points were so we can help you shape your past experiences into a productive solution.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think that it really is javascript in your link, but flash.

But to answer your question: You can use HTML5 Canvas, which provides functions for drawing. You can overwrite the keys and give the mouse special functions. There are plenty of tutorials for this on the web, just search for "html canvas".